# How do I change the fontsize of the base and exponent on my colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

[image]

I'd like to change the size of the base and exponent to match the fontsize of the ticks on my colorbar.  How can I do this?

```
for i in xrange(col):

    plt.plot( t, x[i], color = s_m.to_rgba(slopes[i]), linewidth = 3 )


cbar = plt.colorbar(s_m)
cbar.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))


cbar.update_ticks()

cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, let's cobble together a stand-alone example to demonstrate your problem.  You've changed the size of the colorbar's tick labels, but the offset label didn't update.  For example, it would be nice if the text at the top of the colorbar matched the size of the tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10, 10)) * 1e-6

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)

cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])

plt.show()
```

[image]

What you're wanting to change is referred to as the `offset_text`. In this case, it's the offset text of the y-axis of the colorbar.  You'd want to do something similar to:

```
cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text.set(size=20)
```

or

```
cbar.ax.yaxis.offsetText.set(size=20)
```

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10, 10)) * 1e-6

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)

cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])

cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set(size=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great.  I was able to achieve what I wanted with your post, thanks a lot.